# How to add leadings Zeros to a BigInteger?

Tags: java, integer, biginteger

I want to add leading Zeros to an BigInt, if the BigInt has less than 10 Digits it should add padding Zeros and I have to calculate with the number later on.

Thats my solution so far:

```
BigInteger bankAccountNumber = new BigInteger("999999999");
BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("10000000");
public void checksum(){
    if(bankAccountNumber.toString().length()<10){
        while(bankAccountNumber.toString().length()<10){
            
        }

        System.out.println(bankAccountNumber);
    }
    System.out.println(bankAccountNumber.toString().length());
}
```

My problem is I cant come up with a methode that includes that bankAccountNumber is a real Number with leading 0`s because I have to combine the Number later on with anouther BigInt and this should include leading zeros, all I got is an outprint with leading Zeros, but I cant caculate with that,so thats my problem, thank you for your help.

Comment: A bank account number is not a number. Don't store it as one. It's an ID that happens to be numeric.

Comment: Also, you don't add leading 0's to any type of number. You only add (or "pad") it to the *String representation of a number*. So do that, if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

CAVEAT: As some comments have already pointed out, you're fundamentally applying the wrong approach here. If 'add 1' doesn't make sense to a thing, then **it is a not a number**. Adding 1 to a bank account doesn't do anything sensible, hence, you should be storing that as a String most likely. Anything but a class that extends `Number`.

BigInteger doesn't work like that. It's not a light wrapper around a string. You **cannot** add leading zeroes to it.

Instead, when *printing* the BigInteger (turning it from its standard memory representation to a bunch of characters, e.g. to show to a user), you indicate how you want to do that, and as part of that, you can say: ... pad with zeroes if need be.

```
BigInteger example = BigInteger.ONE;
String ex = String.format("This is the number: %012d", example);
System.out.println(ex);
```

This prints `This is the number: 000000000001` as you wanted. `%012d` is string-format-ese for: "I want to print an integer number (`d`), take up at least 12 character slots (`12`), and if 12 is larger than the number of chars needed to render `example`, pad it out with zeroes (`0`).